# jQuery UI Dragging - which handler is being used?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, drag-and-drop, handle

I got the following setup for dragdrop functionality:

```
const listDragOptions = {
    handle: ".camera, .texter", // dragged by either camera or edit icon
    //revert: true, // so dragged elements fall back to their original position,
    revertDuration: 200, // the element goes back instantly, no need for effects on this one
    snap: true, // snap to table cell edges
    helper: "clone", // create a cloned element instead of moving the original one
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        // tell me which handle is being used!
    }
}
```

Basically I need to know which of the two handles ".camera, .texter" the user has clicked to achieve ddragging functionality.
This seems tricky. I can't find anything in the API, so I'm really willing to accept any dirty hack.

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 1):

I've not had chance to test this, but are you able to grab the id using -

```
$(ui.draggable).attr("id")
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this doesn't help. I need to know which handler inside the `ui.draggable` (or actually: `ui.helper`) element is being used.
Pseudo-Code:

```
//return the id of the handler currently used to move the element
$(":handler", ui.helper).attr("id");
```

However I have solved the problem by just adding another draggable element. It's too bad though.